# CPLEX Java StaticLex is not applicable for (iloNumexpr, iloNumexpr)

Tags: java, cplex

I need to blend two objective functions f1 and f2 ([see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB157.png)) where c is a continuous variable, C_{ug} is a binary variable and a,d and f are parameters. I'm using Cplex Studio IDE 22.1.0  Java in eclipse.

```
// create the objetive function f1
     IloLinearNumExpr firstPart = cplex.linearNumExpr();
     int aSum = 0;
     for (int k = 0; k < inst.n + inst.m; k++) {
         firstPart.addTerm(1, c[k]);
       aSum += -inst.a[k];
     }
     firstPart.setConstant(aSum);

     
     IloLinearNumExpr secondPart = cplex.linearNumExpr();
     for (int k = 0; k < inst.n + inst.m; k++) {
         // This is the equivalent to z[k] = max(c[k] - d[k], 0)
         cplex.addEq(z[k], cplex.max(0,  cplex.sum(c[k], -inst.d[k])));
          secondPart.addTerm(inst.f[k], z[k]);

     }


     IloLinearNumExpr objective = cplex.linearNumExpr();        
     objective.add(firstPart);
     objective.add(secondPart);

 
     
     // create the objetive function f2
        IloLinearNumExpr secobj = cplex.linearNumExpr();       
     for (int tt = 0; tt < inst.T; tt++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < inst.q; k++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < inst.B; j++) {

         secobj.addTerm(1, C[j][k]);
       
     }}}
     

      IloCplex.staticLex(objective, secobj );
```

I'm getting the following error: the method staticLex(IloNumExpr, String) in the type IloCplex is not applicable for the arguments (IloLinearNumExpr, IloLinearNumExpr).
Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? Many thanks.

Comment: What arguments does the staticLex function take?

Comment: It takes the two objective functions "objective" and "secobj" which are IloNumExpr. But the arguments should be IlonNumVar to work.